# How to auto-submit Rails formhelper, when onchange occurs on select dropdown (populated from DB)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formhelper

I have a form in my View with two dropdowns, both populated from db tables, where I'd like to auto-submit the form when onchange event occurs on either dropdown:

```
<%= form_for @products, url: products_path, method: :get do |f| %>
  <!-- POPULATE DROPDOWNS FROM DB DATA -->
  <%= select('post', 'state', @suppliers.collect {|s| [s.supp_state, s.id]}) %>
  <%= select('post', 'category_id', @categories.collect {|c| [c.cat_name, c.id]}) %>
  <div class='actions inline'><%= f.submit 'GO!' %></div>
<% end %>
```

I tried variants of the following but I'm quite new at Ruby/Rails/JS.. no luck so far:

```
<%= select('post', 'state', @suppliers.collect {|s| [s.supp_state, s.id]}, :onchange => "this.form.submit()") %>

<%= select('post', 'state', @suppliers.collect {|s| [s.supp_state, s.id]}, :input_html => {:onchange => "this.form.submit()") %>
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select

The arguments goes like this:

```
select(object, method, choices, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

`:onchange` belongs to html options thus you need to fix your select box to this:

```
select('post', 'state', @suppliers.collect {|s| [s.supp_state, s.id]}, :onchange => "this.form.submit()")
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't like the 'nil' (I'm in Rails 4). I get:  "NoMethodError in Products#home. undefined method `delete' for nil:NilClass" in that line of code

Comment: Ok. I fixed the answer to not contain the nil. I hope it is correct this way.

Comment: I think that's pretty much what I had. No errors but it doesn't auto-submit on change. Must click the submit button.

Comment: Then fire up your chrome or whatever browser you have, see that generated HTML is correct. You may also try a more simple event like `alert("hello")` and see if it works.