# Trying to create a form that automatically submits and reloads page upon change

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like a dropdown box and as a user selects a new option from it, it should **automatically save** (without a submit button) and the page should **reload**.

As it is, however, selecting a value from the dropdown box does not do anything: it does not save nor reload the page. Anyone got an idea how to get the code below to work?

Form:

```
<%= form_for @user, method: :patch, url: set_preference_path do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <%= f.collection_select :default_relationship_id, @organizations, :id, :name, {onchange: "this.form.submit();"}, {class: 'form-control input-md'} %>
        # default_relationship_id is the column in users table to save to, @organizations are the selectable options, id is the value of the options to save, and name is the name to be displayed.
<% end %>
```

Does `onchange: "this.form.submit();"` perhaps not work when using `collection_select`? The examples from which I adapted this implementation (stackoverflow.com/a/24315219 and stackoverflow.com/a/17663373) use it in combination with `select` instead of `collection_select`.

Controller:

```
def overview
  @user = current_user
  @organizations = @user.organizations.where('fish = ?', true)
end

def set_preference
  @user = current_user
  @rel = Relationship.where('user_id = ? and organization_id = ? and fish = ?', @user.id, params[:user][:default_relationship_id], true).first
  @user.update_attributes(default_relationship_id: @rel.id)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render inline: "location.reload();" }
    format.html { redirect_to overview_path(@user) }
  end
end
```

The html code this produces:

```
<form class="edit_user" id="edit_user_1" action="/set_preference/test1" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2*3;" /><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="m/9ECijmnYQ==" />   
<select class="form-control input-md" name="user[default_relationship_id]" id="user_default_relationship_id">
<option value="1">Example1 business</option>
<option value="56">Example2</option>
</form>
```

Comment: How I understand it this should be possible with javascript. See for example these posts: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24315219 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/17663373.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're specifying `:onclick` in the `options` hash instead of the `html_options` hash (where `:class` is specified), so move it to the correct hash, but keep the `options` hash blank:

```
f.collection_select :default_relationship_id, @organizations, :id, :name, {}, {class: 'form-control input-md', onchange: "this.form.submit();"}
```

See the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select) for the the full arguments list.

**ETA** The chosen value of `@user.default_relationship_id` isn't selected by `collection_select` because it refers to a relationship, but you've given the collection `@organizations`. Since `collection_select` can't find the associated organization from a relationship ID, it selects the first option by default. You should refactor so `collection_select` receives a `@relationships` collection. The refactoring should be such that you can update directly from strong params:

```
set_preference
  …
  @user.update user_relationship_params
  …
end

private
def user_relationship_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:default_relationship_id)
end
```

Read up on [form helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#dealing-with-model-objects) for more information.

Comment: Note that while this will work, Javier is correct that Ajax will provide a better solution: it avoids extra page loads that can annoy users and unnecessarily burden your app. Perhaps you can look at implementing Ajax after you have it working without Ajax :)

Comment: Great, it works with one exception: the value selected on loading the page is not the value the record actually has. After loading it always has the value selected that alphabetically comes first. I checked with `debugger` to see if it does save when a new variable is selected and it indeed does. Is there a way to correct this so that its initial selected option is the record's value?  P.S. I'm just starting to learn how to program; the idea indeed is to get my first app working (so I've got something to show for) and then learn more about refactoring and implementing more effective code.

Comment: Thanks @eirikir. `User` and `Organization` have a many-to-many relationship through `Relationship`. I now define `@relationships` in `def overview`. In the view: `f.collection_select :default_relationship_id, @relationships, :id, :name, {}, {onchange: "this.form.submit();"}`. The problem is `name` (the option values to be displayed): this is a column from the `Organization` table (i.e., the `organization` that belongs to the `relationship`). Now that I use `@relationships` instead of `@organizations` it no longer recognizes what I mean by `name` (also tried `:organization.name`).

Comment: @marty in Relationship model, add `delegate :name, to: :organization`

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery, try to [handle onchange event](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) and try [ajax post](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

---

Javascript snippet:

```
/**
 * Assume jQuery script on head
 */
<script type="text/javascript">

  /**
   * Handle onchange on user_default_relationship_id
   */
  $("#user_default_relationship_id").change(function () {

    var data = $( this ).form.serialize();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: <%= set_preference_path %>,
      data: data,
      dataType: "application/json"
    })
    .done(function() {
      // handle done event ...
    })
    .fail(function() {
      // handle fail event ...
    })
    .always(function() {
      // handle event ...
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but shouldn't the code that I have also work? I've adapted `onchange: "this.form.submit();"` from stackoverflow.com/a/24315219 and stackoverflow.com/a/17663373. But for some reason this does not do anything in my use case.

Comment: Don't do `form.submit()`, do it with `ajax`!

Comment: @Marty Answer + Code Snippet = downvote? Thanks a lot

Comment: Well I'll make it an upvote then, but it's not really answering my question. The `form.submit` seems much easier, look for example here: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3902606. I'm looking for the reason why my code is failing.