# add dropdown box, which will include paperclip object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a drop down box, which will include my attachment name as well as the attached object(which uses paperclip).  Once they select an attachment from the dropdown box, I'd like the user to be able to download the report.  Have tried traditional select methods, to no avail.  Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!  Here is my view code, which allows me to download the report.

```
<h2>Policy Value Reports</h2>

<% @user.attachments.each do |attachment| %>

  <p>
   <%= link_to attachment.name, attachment.report.url %>
  </p>

<% end %>


<%= collection_select(:attachment, :report, Attachment.all, :id, :name) %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do this is using the rails formhelper select (with the html option :onchange), which will easily help you creating the drop down box you want, i recommend you to read this:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html

and then this:

[How to auto-submit Rails formhelper, when onchange occurs on select dropdown (populated from DB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17663099/how-to-auto-submit-rails-formhelper-when-onchange-occurs-on-select-dropdown-po)

**EDIT**

I made a simple example which you can try translate into your code.

I have a model User which has an attachment of any type (images or docs) using Paperclip called "photo", and I did a dropdown list with all users and when I select one of them I automatically download (redirect) the attachment associated by using this code:

```
<%= collection_select :user, :photo, User.all, :photo, :name, {}, {:onchange => "window.location.replace(this.value);"}%>
```

or

```
<%= select_tag 'Users_List', options_from_collection_for_select(@users, "photo", "id"),:onchange => "window.location.replace(this.value);" %>
```

In your case, I would try something like this:

```
<%= collection_select :attachment, :report, Attachment.all, :report, :name, {}, {:onchange => "window.location.replace(this.value);"}%>
```

I hope it works for you.

Comment: thanks soltex, that helped!  I posted the new views code above.  I can now create a dropbox selection that shows all available attachments, but am struggling to complete the last step -- download the selected attachment.  Looked into the second link you provided, but couldn't translate into my code.

Comment: No problem, I will edit my post, I think I have a solution for your problem which maybe you can translate into your code.

Comment: @soltex, that works, THANK YOU, THANK YOU!  :)  I've been struggling with this for nearly a week now.  Quick question: do you have a resource which highlights various :onchange commands?  I'd like to be create a button that will allow the user the option to download(which would pop up in a new window), as opposed to it automatically downloading.

Comment: No, I dont have any resources about it, I usually dont use it, but :onchange is an HTML event attribute, so I think you can easily find alots of information. So, for what I understand, you want a button to do the same function and open the file in another window? If so, you can do that by using a form_for and a submit button I guess.

Comment: yeah, I was thinking the same thing, regarding the form_for.  Thank you.

Comment: "window.open(this.value);"  This will open up a new window, instead of replacing the current window.